# Why am I getting an SSL Error on http request

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

The following code

```cs
using var response = await http.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/resource").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

is giving me an SSL error:

> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

The inner exception is as follows:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Why is this http request attempting to use SSL?  Any ideas as to how to fix this?  I can access this API through postman with no problem.

Comment: is the server using HSTS?

Comment: may you are redirecting all requests from http to https

Comment: How would I check these things?  I am sending http from postman and the server accepts it just fine from there, so I was assuming that it was the client code... but the client code is exactly this (except for resource name), so it's very much straight forward.

Comment: have a look on the server code UseHttps under the UseKestrel option most likely in the Program.cs file.  also, type the address in a browser to see if you get the same error.

Comment: @GaryHolland in program.cs on the server there was a call to `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` removing that fixed the issue.  Any idea why it was accepting my postman requests?

Comment: Regardless, thank you, you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Jesse, because by default Postman will automatically follow redirects.